# Solving an indefinite integral?

Tags: integration

How can we solve the indefinite integral

> $$\int \frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt a}{\sqrt x-\sqrt a}{dx}$$

Can we use the substitution method?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please edit your question text to at least include the answer you got. This way, we can compare what you got with the correct answer and, if they're different, may be able to determine what you did incorrectly. Also, note you can fairly easily check if your solution is correct by differentiating it to see if you get back the integral expression. Did you try this and, if so, what result did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the step-by-step solution:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Integrate as follows,

$$\int \frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt a}{\sqrt x-\sqrt a}{dx}$$
$$=\int (1+\frac {2\sqrt a}{\sqrt x-\sqrt a})dx$$
$$=x +4\sqrt a \int \frac{\sqrt x }{\sqrt x- \sqrt a}d\sqrt x$$
$$=x +4\sqrt a \int (1+  \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt x- \sqrt a})d\sqrt x$$

$$=x +4\sqrt {ax } + 4a\ln(\sqrt x -\sqrt a) + C $$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please explain step 3 onwards.

Comment: It is equivalent to the substitution $t=\sqrt x$

Answer (score 3):

We can rationalise the function in the integral to get :
$$\int \frac{x+a+2\sqrt{xa}}{x-a} dx$$
Which can be written as :
$$ \int \frac{x}{x-a} dx +\int \frac{a}{x-a} dx +2 \sqrt{a}\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-a} dx$$
This can be further simplified to get your answer

Comment: +1 note that $x+a=x-a+2a$

Comment: Yes that seems like a good way to proceed !

Comment: That's how I did it. But I'm not quite sure how to solve the 3rd integral (the one with √ax)

Comment: We can substitute √x as u to get a simpler integral. Splitting the integral as a telescopic sum helps after this.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the denominator, let
$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}=t \implies x=(t+\sqrt{a})^2\implies dx=2(t+\sqrt{a})\,dt$$ and all of this makes after simplifcations
$$\int \frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt a}{\sqrt x-\sqrt a}{dx}=\int \left(\frac{4 a}{t}+6 \sqrt{a}+2 t \right)\,dt$$